# How to specify a path for output file in ffmpeg?

Tags: php, windows, ffmpeg

I am trying to give a path for the output file, but ffmpeg is giving an error stating

> Unable to find a suitable output format for '/kcs/eng/: Invalid argument.

Whereas it is accepting the full path of the input file.

```
$in_path = "D:/kcs/kan/video.vob";
$out_path = "E:/kcs/eng/video.mp4";

ffmpeg -i $in_path -loglevel error -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -strict experimental $out_Path
```

How to specify the path of the output file?

Comment: You're also using the wrong slashes for Windows.  Use a backslash.

Answer (score 3):

The command is not able to understand the output file type. Try **-f mp4** option to specify that you want output to be in mp4 format.

One more point is first try to create the file in the same directory from where you are executing the command, so the out_path would be,

$out_path = "video.mp4";

Comment: file is getting created in same folder where the input file is present. if i do so, there will be a complexity in file names. as all input files are in the name VTS_VID_01.VOB.. all input files are supplied from different folders. So the output files must be created in different folders respectively

Answer (score 2):

Run the code in python file , and use concatenation process

```
cmd='ffmpeg -i C:/streaming/sample_videos/'+x+' -i logo.png -filter_complex "overlay=10:10" -preset slow -g 48 -sc_threshold 48  -map 0:0 -map 0:1  -s:v:0 640x360 -c:v:0 libx264 -b:v:0  800k -c:a:0 aac -b:a:0 96k   -c:a copy -var_stream_map "v:0,a:0" -profile:v main  -master_pl_name master.m3u8 -f hls -hls_time 20 -hls_list_size 0 -hls_playlist_type vod -hls_segment_filename "'+y+'/stream_%v/file_%03d.ts" '+y+'/stream_%v/playlist.m3u8'
subprocess.call(cmd,shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

@Karthikeya Vaidya Your output path should be

```
$out_path = "D:/kcs/eng/video.mp4";
```

Please change the path as above.

Comment: @ Sanjay Khatri No changes...! still the error message is same. is there any other method to specify a path for output file.

Comment: @KarthikeyaVaidya Which version of ffmpeg are you using?

Comment: @ Sanjay Khatri  ffmpeg version N-65142-gd76675d Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
built on Jul 31 2014 22:02:01 with gcc 4.8.3 (GCC)